# hiding config on web site

Tags: php, web-services

I'm creating a php script that will use another php script (login.php) file to store database login information. This file will sit within the public_html directory of the website to interact with the mysql database.

I'm wondering what the best approach to file security would be, so that someone can't access the login.php file containing the login credentials.

Comment: And how would they do that?

Comment: @RiggsFolly couldn't they just access domain.com/login.php ?

Comment: If they accessed it through the web server, it will be executed by PHP and they would only get whatever it outputs. Which is probably nothing? (I assume it just defines some variables.)

Comment: A: Place it outside the public area.